# How to show that $f^{-1}$ respects set theoretic operations

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am trying to prove the inverse image w.r.t a continuous function f:R->R of every closed set is closed.  I am trying to use the fact that f is continuous means for every open subset O$\subset$R, its inverse image $f^{-1}$(O) is open.

Here is my proof:
Let $C$ be closed, $C \subset R$.  Then $R$ \ $C$ is open and so is $f^{-1}(R$ \ $C$).  I need to show that this = $f^{-1}(C)$, but I'm stuck

Comment: So, you're asking why the inverse image of the complement is the complement of the inverse image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in f^{-1}(R\setminus C)$, then $f(x)\in R\setminus C$. Therefore, $f(x)\not\in C$, so $x\not\in f^{-1}(C)$. This puts $x\in R\setminus f^{-1}(C)$.

This argument, by element-chasing, shows that the inverse image of the complement is contained in the complement of the inverse-image. By element-chasing, you can show the converse as well.

Answer (score 2):

The following statements are equivalent:

- $x\in f^{-1}(C^{\complement})$
- $f(x)\in C^{\complement}$
- $f(x)\notin C$
- $x\notin f^{-1}(C)$
- $x\in f^{-1}(C)^{\complement}$

So we have: $$x\in f^{-1}(C^{\complement})\iff x\in f^{-1}(C)^{\complement}$$ for arbitrary $x$.

This tells us that: $$f^{-1}(C^{\complement})=f^{-1}(C)^{\complement}$$